# Terraform Azure CDN endpoint - Delivery_rule

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-azure

we have multiple action in the deliver rule for the cdn endpoint in azure. Using the terraform how can I add multiple and condition for the modify_response_header or any other attribute.

```
delivery_rule       = {
  name              = "CORS"
  order             = "1"
  request_header_condition = {
    operator =  "Equal"
    selector =  "Origin"  ##HeaderValue
    match_values = ["https://x.x.x.sdfad"]
  }
  modify_response_header_action = {
    action  =   "Overwrite"
    value   =   "*"
    name    =   "Access-Control-Allow-Methods"   ---> 1st value
  }

modify_response_header_action = {
    action  =   "Overwrite"
    value   =   "*"
    name    =   "Access-Control-Allow-Origin"    ----> 2nd value 
  }
  modify_request_header_action = {
    action  =   "Overwrite"
    value   =   "*"
    name    =   "Access-Control-Allow-Headers"
  }
}
```

in azure portal, we can add multiple action/condition in the same rule for the same type.

If add another type, its getting overwrite

```
      ~ delivery_rule {
            name  = "CORS"
            # (1 unchanged attribute hidden)

          ~ modify_response_header_action {
              ~ name   = "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" -> "Access-Control-Allow-Methods"
                # (2 unchanged attributes hidden)
            }

            # (3 unchanged blocks hidden)
        }

        # (1 unchanged block hidden)
    }
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tG2li.png)

---

how can I add the the multiple action for the same condition for the cdn_endpoint in azure,

Below is the azure cdn_endpoint deliver rule json, I want to achieve this in terraform.

```
{
                    "name": "CORS",
                    "order": 1,
                    "conditions": [                    -------------->   1 condition
                        {
                            "name": "RequestHeader",
                            "parameters": {
                                "operator": "Equal",
                                "selector": "Origin",
                                "negateCondition": false,
                                "matchValues": [
                                    "https://xdafd..sds."
                                ],
                                "transforms": [],
                                "@odata.type": "#Microsoft.Azure.Cdn.Models.DeliveryRuleRequestHeaderConditionParameters"
                            }
                        }
                    ],
                    "actions": [                             ---------------->  Multiple action for same ModifyResponseHeader
                        {
                            "name": "ModifyResponseHeader",
                            "parameters": {
                                "headerAction": "Overwrite",
                                "headerName": "Access-Control-Allow-Origin",
                                "value": "*",
                                "@odata.type": "#Microsoft.Azure.Cdn.Models.DeliveryRuleHeaderActionParameters"
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "ModifyResponseHeader",
                            "parameters": {
                                "headerAction": "Overwrite",
                                "headerName": "Access-Control-Allow-Methods",
                                "value": "*",
                                "@odata.type": "#Microsoft.Azure.Cdn.Models.DeliveryRuleHeaderActionParameters"
                            }
                        },
                        {
```

Comment: I assume this is one of the recent versions of Terraform that omits output to be less verbose by default. Examining your plan output impies that if you display the plan in full verbosity then you will observe that all the rules are being configured correctly, but that one is being updated to correctly match your config.

Comment: I am importing the cdn endpoint which has 3 rule and it's trying to overwrite. It's not matching the existing created rule condition

Answer (score 1):

> I tried to add the the multiple action for the same condition for the cdn_endpoint in azure using terraform and I was able to provision the requirement successfully.

It appears you're trying to specify multiple `modify_response_header_action` configurations within a single `delivery_rule` block in Terraform for Azure CDN. When you add another configuration of the same type, it overwrites the previous one, which isn't the behavior you want.

In Terraform, to specify multiple configurations of the same type within a block, you should use a list of maps. Each map within the list will represent a single `modify_response_header_action` configuration.

**My file structure:**

```
my-cdn-terraform/
│
├── main.tf
├── variables.tf
│
└── modules/
    │
    └── cdn/
        ├── main.tf
        └── variables.tf
```

**My terraform configuration:**

##### main.tf:

```
provider "azurerm" {
    features {}
}

module "cdn" {
  source = "./modules/cdn"

  resource_group_name  = "v-sakavya"
  location             = "East US"
  cdn_profile_name     = "myCDNvksbProfile"
  cdn_endpoint_name    = "myCDNvksbEndpoint"
  origin_host_name     = "www.examplevksb.com"
}
```

##### variable.tf:

```
variable "resource_group_name" {
  description = "The name of the Azure Resource Group"
  type        = string
}

variable "location" {
  description = "The Azure region for resources"
  type        = string
}

variable "cdn_profile_name" {
  description = "The name of the Azure CDN profile"
  type        = string
}

variable "cdn_endpoint_name" {
  description = "The name of the Azure CDN endpoint"
  type        = string
}

variable "origin_host_name" {
  description = "The origin hostname for the CDN endpoint"
  type        = string
}
```

##### `./modules/cdn/main.tf:

```
resource "azurerm_cdn_profile" "this" {
  name                = var.cdn_profile_name
  resource_group_name = var.resource_group_name
  location            = var.location
  sku                 = "Standard_Microsoft"
}

resource "azurerm_cdn_endpoint" "this" {
  name                = var.cdn_endpoint_name
  location            = var.location
  profile_name        = azurerm_cdn_profile.this.name
  resource_group_name = var.resource_group_name

  origin {
    name      = "contentOrigin"
    host_name = var.origin_host_name
  }

  delivery_rule {
    name  = "CORS"
    order = 1

    request_header_condition {
      operator     = "Equal"
      selector     = "Origin"
      match_values = ["https://example.com"]
    }

    modify_response_header_action {
      action = "Overwrite"
      value  = "*"
      name   = "Access-Control-Allow-Methods"
    }

    modify_response_header_action {
      action = "Overwrite"
      value  = "*"
      name   = "Access-Control-Allow-Origin"
    }

    modify_response_header_action {
      action = "Overwrite"
      value  = "*"
      name   = "Access-Control-Allow-Headers"
    }
  }
}
```

use the same **`variable file`** here inside the module as well.

**Output:**

[image]

[image]

Comment: Are you able to see both the action for this attribute in the rule engine option for the endpoint?  can you please the module for reference?

Comment: It worked! Thank you!